# Apple Developer forum - Not able to log in into Developer forum

Tags: apple-id, developer-program

I am not able to login into apple developer forum every time it takes me to create a new user account page and the displays the error, I have successfully validated with multiple user name as below screen shot -

[image]

when i try to hit submit it gives me below error -

[image]

I have already reported it to apple using bug reporter with id `27240362`  but there is no response from their side. I am hoping to get some help here.

Comment: Did you clear cookies etc, tried with a different browser, from a different user account on your Mac (create one if necessary)?

Comment: Also, reaching out to Apple Support might be better than creating a bug with Bugreporter.

Comment: Yes I did try every other options i.e clearing cookies, trying different browser and trying different location and ISPs as well, nothing seems working.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a *Customer Support* issue with the Apple Developer site; support questions should be directed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally after one year of effort one of the kind apple engineer replied to my ticket and the issue resolved and closed now. Please find below response from apple just in case any one is looking for it -

> Please note that there is an issue with non-standard email domains. We kindly ask you to create a new Apple ID with .com domain, and try to access the Forums with that. You don’t need to have an active paid membership to access the Forums.

Comment: Thanks so much for relaying this - likely many people had the same experience as you since there are multiple threads with multiple votes on posts in them.

Comment: Thank you, I just got the response from apple and hence thought it would definitely help others.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're a registered Developer, I would call the Apple Developer Program Support number for your country, rather than submitting a bug.

You can find your local number [here](https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone/).